# Formatting Date with month names in different languages using date pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, locale, date-pipe

I am displaying date in html like this

```
<span >{{ item.lastModified | date : 'MMM d, y' }}</span>
```

So the date displays something like this `Jul 20, 2021`
Now when I change my browser language I need the month to change to that language the language should be picked up dynamically , but its displaying in English. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to set yours '**locale**':

1. In your *app.module.ts*:

```
    // Import all the languages you need (you can add any language you want i.e: '../locales/en-GB', '/locales/en-US', ... ).
    // In this example, I will use 'es' for Spanish and 'fr' for French:
    import myLocaleEs from '@angular/common/locales/es'
    import myLocaleFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr'

    import {registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';

    registerLocaleData(myLocaleEs);
    registerLocaleData(myLocaleFr);
```

2. In your HTML:

```
    // "en" is always by default, you don't need to register
    {{ fecha | date: "long":"":"en" }}
    
    {{ fecha | date: "long":"":"es" }}

    
    {{ fecha | date: "short":"":"fr" }}
or  {{ fecha | date: 'MMM d, y':"":"fr" }}
```

---

**Set Globally**

It is a way to set "globaly" your favorite locale (if it's different to "en", the default), so then you don't need to write it down in every pipe:

You need to add to *app.module.t*s, **besides all the above code**, this import and the PROVIDERS section:

```
...
import { LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';
...

...
providers: [
    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'es'} // Same value you used above ‘es’ or 'fr' or whatever you had registered
  ],
...
```